# How to display a set using ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this json set that needs to be displayed (in columns):

```
  {
   "2": [
         {
           "$id": "1",
           "serverId": 1622,
           "innCode": "PLOIKJ7",
           "propertyName": "Property 1",
          },
         {
           "$id": "2",
           "serverId": 1622,
           "innCode": "BHGTRWA",
           "propertyName": "Property 2",
          }
        ],
     "3": [
          {
            "$id": "3",
             "serverId": 1623,
             "innCode": "TGHRE#W",
             "propertyName": "Property 3",
           }
        ]
  }
```

I can't think of a way to "loop" through it using ng-repeat. I have the following template defined as a starter:

```
  <div ng-repeat="s in sets">
       <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading"><span><bold>Server:&nbsp;{{s.serverNum}}</bold></span></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="all#" ng-click="doNothing($event)"/>Select All
                </div>
                <div class="divider">&nbsp;</div>
                <div ng-repeat="p in s.properties">
                   <label class="margin-right12">
                       <input type="checkbox"                                                                        name="property_{{p.innCode}}"
                          value="{{p.innCode}}" ng-click="doNothing($event)"/> <small>{{innCode}} - {{p.propertyName}}</small>
               </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this
Inside the controller

```
$scope.data = {
   "2": [
         {
           "$id": "1",
           "serverId": 1622,
           "innCode": "PLOIKJ7",
           "propertyName": "Property 1",
          },
         {
           "$id": "2",
           "serverId": 1622,
           "innCode": "BHGTRWA",
           "propertyName": "Property 2",
          }
        ],
     "3": [
          {
            "$id": "3",
             "serverId": 1623,
             "innCode": "TGHRE#W",
             "propertyName": "Property 3",
           }
        ]
  };
```

Inside the template

```
<div ng-controller="yourCntroName">
        <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in data">// By this line you will get all keys of your set. '2' and '3' in your case
            <div ng-repeat="obj in val"> // val will give you value of key(first time '2' and second time '3' in your case) that is an array so again use repeat.
                {{'$id = '+obj.$id+' ,'}}{{'serverId = '+obj.serverId}}
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide UI of display in coloumn ?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the built-in `ng-repeat` directive is available [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Based on that documentation, the applicable expression for your use case should be `ng-repeat="(key, value) in expression"`. `expression` should be substituted with `set` in your code.

Eventually you should arrive at something like this:

```
  <div ng-repeat="(count, servers) in sets">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <span><bold>Server:&nbsp;{{count}}</bold></span>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" value="all#" ng-click="doNothing($event)" />Select All
        </div>
        <div class="divider">&nbsp;</div>
        <div ng-repeat="server in servers">
          <label class="margin-right12">
            <input type="checkbox" name="property_{{server.innCode}}" value="{{server.innCode}}" ng-click="doNothing($event)" /> <small>{{server.innCode}} - {{server.propertyName}}</small>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Your markup could use a lot of improvement, but one thing at a time - **I suggest you read the doc**.